# How to forward external port to internal port using plink

Tags: windows, ssh, ports

For a penetration test where I have shell access to a computer running an old Windows, I'd like to forward port 4450 to 127.0.0.1:445 because the firewall is blocking 445 externally.

I'm stuck on the following:

`plink -L 4450:127.0.0.1:445 SSH-Server`

According to the documentation I've found, I'd have to specify a SSH-Server. But all documentation I've found just uses an SSH-Server in the same network. To forward it to a localhost port, that wouldn't help.

Do I have to install an SSH-Server on that machine or are there other ways?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you have an ssh client on the Windows system, *and* you can establish SSH outbound to a system you control, then you can use a *remote port forward*, i.e. with option `-R`. This is effectively the opposite of `-L`, it sets up a listener on the remote (connected to) and forwards back [sic] through the system you're connecting from.

So, run ssh/putty/plink on the windows system with `-R 4450:127.0.0.1:445` or equivalent, and log in to an sshd you control. You can then connect to 127.0.0.1:4450 on that system.

Depending on the nature of your "shell access", other options may include running `socat` or `netcat` across it, e.g.:

```
socat -ddd SYSTEM:"ssh somewhere 'socat TCP4-LISTEN:4450 STDIO'"  TCP:127.0.0.1:445
```

Note this gets you a single connection back only, you need `socat` on each side.

Answer (score 0):

To bypass the firewall in this way you would need an SSH server that is behind the firewall.

Did you get your shell using Metasploit? If you use the Meterpreter payload, it is able to setup a port forward.

http://www.offensive-security.com/metasploit-unleashed/Portfwd

Comment: yes, I did indeed, but looked for plink version. Thought it had to be possible. I do like Portfwd in meterpreter though, didn't know about it. Thanks!